# The relation between Hamiltonian mechanics and geodesic spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, geodesics, equivalence-principle

One way to write the action for a particle moving in curved spacetime is to use the proper time as a parameter and the metric tensor as a function of the coordinates. This leads to an action that is proportional to the length of the geodesic followed by the particle. Another way to write the action is to use a different parameter (such as coordinate time) and introduce a Lagrange multiplier that enforces the constraint that the particle moves along a geodesic. This leads to an action that is proportional to the Hamiltonian function for the particle. Both actions give rise to the same equations of motion, which are equivalent to Hamilton’s equations or geodesic equations.
Does the above make it possible to conclude that the rest energy of a particle can be modelled as a Hamiltonian thanks to Einstein further works on spacetime and it's geodesic nature?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/759654/2451

Answer (score 0):

Having looked further into this, I have been able to ascertain that not only can you model rest mass as an Hamiltonian, it is calculated as $E=mc^2$ (you can study how this is done on youtube [here](https://youtu.be/CgWmJTQw2F0)) .    Further, as the Hamiltonian relates to a fully mechanical systems the rest mass energy may easily be equated to a mechanical work energy.   Thence, $mc^2$ can be equated to $ma.S$ where, $a$ is an acceleration and $S$ is a Lorentz invariant path of least action (NB/ since the only acceleration acting on a rest mass is small $g$ then $S$ is of considerable magnitude...)